# Append / copy table row with a dropdown value from database in javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, forms

I have a dropdown value from database in table row,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="addbutton">Add Item</button>
<table class="table" id="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <select >
              <option selected="" disabled="">--Select Product Name--</option>
                <?php
                $con = new mysqli($host, $dbid, $dbpass, $dbname);
                $stmt = $con->prepare( "SELECT name FROM product ORDER BY name DESC" );
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                $con->close();
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                  echo '<option value="'.$row["name"].'">'.$row["name"].'</option>';
                }
              ?>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

if I click add button, I want to append the row that have same dropdown without make a database query again (for a dropdown value). 
I have make jQuery to add row

```
  $("#addbutton").click(function(){
    $('#table tr:last').after(' _??_ ');
  });
```

what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have implemented by selecting the `<tr>` that contains the `select` then [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) it and using [`.appendTo()`](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) you can have added to the table, here is a working snippet:

```js
$('#addbutton').click(function() {
  $('table tr:last-child').clone().appendTo($('table'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="addbutton">Add Item</button>
<table class="table" id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option selected="" disabled="">--Select Product Name--</option>
                    <option selected="" disabled="">option1</option>
                    <option selected="" disabled="">option2</option>
                    <option selected="" disabled="">option3</option>
                    <option selected="" disabled="">option4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: wow , great answer , but in my code it give me copy the header too. i have edited to 
` var $last = $("#table tbody").find('tr:last'); $last.clone().appendTo($('table')) ` and it works as expected. Thank you